# What's bigger than a double?

Tags: c++, types, variables

Is there a native c++ variable type that's "bigger" than a double?
float is 7
double is 15  (of course depending on the compiler)
Is there anything bigger that's native, or even non-native?

Comment: I usually think of float as 4 and double as 8, but you're referring to the approximate number of decimal digits, whereas I'm referring to the number of bytes used.

Comment: A triple! (bah dum, chh!)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

C++ has `long double`, but there is no guarantee that it's any more precise than a plain `double`. On an x86 platform, usually `double` is 64 bits, and `long double` is either 64 or 80 bits (which gives you 19 significant figures, if I remember right).

Your mileage may vary, especially if you're not on x86.

Answer (score 13):

A long double typically only uses 10 bytes, but due to alignment may actually take up 12 or 16 (depending on the compiler and options) bytes in a structure.

The 10 byte long double provides a 64-bit mantissa; this is very convenient for when you want to store 64 bit integers in floating point without loss of precision.

Answer (score 10):

You can use [GNU MP](http://gmplib.org/). Its [floating-point functions](http://gmplib.org/manual/Floating_002dpoint-Functions.html#Floating_002dpoint-Functions) have unlimited mantissa and 32-bit or 64-bit (depending on the native word size) exponent. It also comes with a [C++ wrapper](http://gmplib.org/manual/C_002b_002b-Interface-Floats.html#C_002b_002b-Interface-Floats).

Answer (score 3):

There are also some various bigfloat/bigint libraries around for C++ that allow arbitrary precision math. There's [this](http://www.codeplex.com/BigFloat) library on Microsoft Codeplex, but Googling will find you plenty of others.

Answer (score 3):

C++ has long double, but it's still quite limited. For good time try GNU's gmp library. You can set up numbers as big as you like, and it's quite fun and hackishly when you use gmp_add instead of a normal +. I'm sure there's a C++ wrapper somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

long double, but it generally is still 15 places of precision too.

Answer (score 2):

long long double only some cpus will allow you to use it though...

Answer (score 0):

Boost 1.53 or higher has multiprecision.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html