# Failed To Deploy Flask App On Heroku [fatal error: mpfr.h: No such file or directory]

Tags: python, heroku, flask

I already made simple web app using Flask and wanted to deploy it at Heroku, but found this error when deploying :

> ```
>        Complete output from command /app/.heroku/python/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-yc_idc80/gmpy2/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-dh_wvxtt-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
>        running install
>        running build
>        running build_ext
>        building 'gmpy2' extension
>        creating build
>        creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
>        creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/src
>        gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DWITHMPFR -DWITHMPC -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python3.6m -c src/gmpy2.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/src/gmpy2.o
>        In file included from src/gmpy2.c:426:0:
>        src/gmpy.h:252:20: fatal error: mpfr.h: No such file or directory
>        compilation terminated.
>        error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1  
>        ----------------------------------------
> ```

Comment: maybe, this answer related with your problem
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46019674/c-boost-multiprecision-fatal-error-mpfr-h-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: So, Do I need to install MPFR in Heroku ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem with `gmpy2` and I solved it today:

```
apt install libgmp-dev libmpfr-dev libmpc-dev
```

Comment: Did you solve it in Heroku or just in your machine?